# Mysql - hierarchical recursive query

Tags: mysql, recursive-query

I have a MySQL table which is as follows:

| Id | Name | Parent_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Admin | 2 |
| 2 | Admin2 | 3 |
| 3 | SuperAdmin | 0 |
| 31 | User1 | 1 |
| 32 | User2 | 31 |
| 33 | User3 | 32 |

I use mysql query:

```
select  id,
        username,
        parent_id 
from    (select * from products
         order by parent_id, id) products_sorted,
        (select @pv := '0') initialisation
where   find_in_set(parent_id, @pv)
and     length(@pv := concat(@pv, ',', id))
```

But when trying to get the entire hierarchy, starting with parent_id=0 I only get:

| Id | Name | Parent_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | SuperAdmin | 0 |
| 2 | Admin2 | 3 |

Help fix the error.
Unfortunately, it is not possible to change the id, parent_id.

Mysql v. 8.0.27

[My sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/47c76a)

If parent_id=0, I expect:

| Id | Name | Parent_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | SuperAdmin | 0 |
| 2 | Admin2 | 3 |
| 1 | Admin | 2 |
| 31 | User1 | 1 |
| 32 | User2 | 31 |
| 33 | User3 | 32 |

Comment: MySQL 5.x does not support recursive queries. You must use iterative stored procedure. You may solve your task in single query only when **ALL** rows matches the condition `id > parent_id`.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. Mysql v. 8.0.27

Comment: If so then use common recursive CTE.